# How do I permanently disable swap on archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, swap

I have Archlinux x86_64 installation on my laptop and desktop. At the time of installation, I have created a swap partition with fdisk and enabled that with `sudo swapon /dev/sda3`.

But even with `sysctl vm.swappiness` set to `0`, my system still writes to the swap partition when my system memory is half used, and at the time I copy/move a large file to somewhere, which makes the system very slow. In such case, I used to turn off the swap with `sudo swapoff /dev/sda3`.

Nowadays, I generally turn off the swap after boot,  and enable it when I truly need the swap (and I have a ruby script to monitor RAM usage, and turn on swap when it's needed). Swap is activated again in the next boot. I have no entries in the `/etc/fstab` regarding swap.

Is there a way to permanently disable the swap device without deleting the device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Disabling_swap) mentions that swap on Archlinux is managed by systemd, and describes how to disable automatic activation by masking the systemd unit responsible for swap. Thus, on Archlinux the following should achieve what you are looking for:

1. Disable swap using `#swapoff -a` or pass a specific device/file name for a specific swap. At this point the swap is disabled, but will be automatically reactivated and enabled during next boot.
2. To prevent auto activation of swap, look for the swap systemd units using `#systemctl --type swap`. For each `*.swap` unit found mask it using `#systemctl mask <unit_name>`.

This process can be undone by just running `systemctl unmask <unit_name>` on the previously masked units, and then turning swap on using `swapon`.

This is taken from the following two Archwiki articles:

- [ArchWiki: Swap: Disabling Swap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Disabling_swap)
- [ArchWiki: Systemd: Using Units](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Using_units) (See section on masking and unmasking)

Answer (score 2):

You can let systemd do this by creating the file `/lib/systemd/system/turnswapoff.service` with the contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn swap off 

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/swapoff -a

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And make sure it runs at boot `sudo systemctl enable turnswapoff`

It could be that the location of `swapoff` is not `/sbin/swapoff`. You can check this with `which swapoff` and change it if necessary

Comment: Arch surely uses systemd. Nice answer, I didn't think of it for some reason!

Comment: Yes, this works as usual... But I wonder if there any other ways because it's just equivalent to turning off swap after they are on...

Comment: If your system mounts sda3 as swap and it is not in fstab then it 'magically' knows that sda3 is a swappartion, this really surprises me... If you boot your system (without `turnswapoff`) is there anything swap related mentioned in `/proc/self/mounts` ?

Comment: Yup that's true for every ArchLinux installation I have ever done (except ArchLinux ARM for Raspberry Pi, the swap isn't automatically mounted).

When you create a swap during installation before chrooting, and turn on swap, after the installation, when you reboot it will turn on the device without an fstab entry! Event no genfstab is done! The fstab is completely empty, it has just 3 lines of comments.

There's no match after running `cat /proc/self/mounts | grep -i swap`!

Comment: Sorry, forget about checking `/proc/self/mounts`. I checked my system and it seems swap doesn't show up here anyway...

Comment: How did you check that it was sda3 that was used as swap ? Could it be that a swapfile was used instead of a swappartition ?

Comment: I run `cat /proc/swaps` or `free -h` or a system monitor, generally either `htop` or `gnome-system-monitor` to check for swap...

Comment: And no, I am not using any swapfile. The partition was created by me during the installation of the system with any of one tools like `cfdisk`, `fdisk`, `cgdisk`. The partition was activated before running `pacstrap /mnt/ base`... True for both of the systems.

Comment: If the partitioning tool creates the swap partition with the partition type GUID for swap according to the [Discoverable Partitions Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/), then it is automatically used without the need for it to be listed in `/etc/fstab`.